# PDF drawing sense for `re`

Tags: pdf

I had trouble finding how to define small holes using a clipping path. Eventually I realised I needed to draw the outer limit of the enabled area. I think I then messed up by drawing the disabled areas using `re`. It works, but I think it is probably not reliable.

So the question is: can I rely on the sense (clockwise or anticlockwise (from the viewer)) of drawing by the `re` operator?

Comment: I'm going to change it, just to be safe.

Comment: Did the answers sufficiently answer your question?

Comment: Thanks, yes. I understand that the spec says I'm safe, but have changed it anyway to the safer construct. Some browser might ignore the declared equivalence.

Comment: Great. But if an answer sufficiently answers your question, please mark it as accepted (click the tick at its upper left).

Comment: Hi mkl  I'm not seeing a tick.

Comment: *"I'm not seeing a tick"* - At the top left of the answer to mark, under the voting arrows and the Timeline symbol, there should be a gray tick you can click.It should turn green to mark acceptance. [This](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work) is an old description before the timeline icon was added. Otherwise, though, it should still be correct.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the PDF specification:

> *x y width height*
>   **re**
>   Append a rectangle to the current path as a complete subpath, with lower-left corner (*x, y*) and dimensions *width* and *height* in user space.
>
> The operation:
>
> ```
> x y width height re
> ```
>
> is equivalent to:
>
> ```
> x y m
> ( x + width ) y l
> ( x + width ) ( y + height ) l
> x ( y + height ) l
> h
> ```

*(ISO 32000-2, Table 58 — Path construction operators)*

Thus, if width and height have the same sign (both positive or both negative), it's anti-clockwise, otherwise it's clockwise.

Answer (score 0):

The `re` operator is defined in the spec, it always constructs the rectangular path anti-clockwise. Any PDF consumer which doesn't follow that is going to have problems, because fill and eofill will not behave correctly if the path is constructed differently.

See table 4.9 on page 227 of the PDF 1.7 specification.

Note that clip and eoclip (W and W* in PDF terms) will behave differently depending on the construction of the path.